# Class constructor type extending another and intersecting at the same time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

This is a TS type for a HOC from the `react-router` library:

```
export function withRouter<P extends RouteComponentProps<any>, C extends React.ComponentType<P>>(
    component: C & React.ComponentType<P>,
): React.ComponentClass<Omit<P, keyof RouteComponentProps<any>> & WithRouterProps<C>> & WithRouterStatics<C>;
```

The thing that confuses me is the following: `C extends React.ComponentType<P>` and `C & React.ComponentType<P>`. What is the purpose of the intersection type? Why not only have `component: C` as argument to `withRouter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a trick to get function inference to infer types for both `C` and `P`. Generally type parameters are only inferred form arguments not from other type parameters. So even though we have a relation between `P` and `C` (`P extends RouteComponentProps<any>, C extends React.ComponentType<P>`) `P` will not be inferred based on `C`

```
function X(p: RouteComponentProps<{ p: string }>){
    return null!
}

export declare function withRouter<P extends RouteComponentProps<any>, C extends React.ComponentType<P>>(
    component: C
): React.ComponentClass<Omit<P, keyof RouteComponentProps<any>> & WithRouterProps<C>> & WithRouterStatics<C>;


let x2 = withRouter(X) // P is RouteComponentProps<any>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChRJY4BvOAdWBgAsEIBXGJKABRzAGcANInacAwrkgA7JFJi8IA4Q2asOXAMowUMYGn5wAvnDjZcBIuhgBaHOqhlSmNlIzAIUuAA0AFGABcIuoS4B6y8nz8ADy0AXD8MFDAUgDmRgB8AJTUpCYmRDBsUJ5SbAA2ZQCEpIakpEgAHpTwACZIaGUoRKYubh5wAO6MLKJcUdxwjZxSLQZq4pJhcgoCUShSAJ7pwmKTDdOziMQwAHQh0uEAKhtgSOPp6T65eWiLMnKBYqSZgchWZ29wmJOvxogB5ECMcbCADWSA2EEwQQWoXeEUU0XWW3ScAAZPRhvMuCtomIHniCapRlAtDo9KT0gBuOqkMpIeANABMcAAvINCdSfF5MnAAPSiuATYBzUbnJbo1ZY9JAA)

Now if a parameter is of an intersection type, then the argument for that parameter is used as an inference site for both types in the intersection. So when we have `C & React.ComponentType<P>` the argument `X` will be used to infer both `C` and `P` in `React.ComponentType<P>`.

```
export declare function withRouter<P extends RouteComponentProps<any>, C extends React.ComponentType<P>>(
    component: C &  React.ComponentType<P>
): React.ComponentClass<Omit<P, keyof RouteComponentProps<any>> & WithRouterProps<C>> & WithRouterStatics<C>;


let x2 = withRouter(X) // P is { p: string }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChRJY4BvOAdWBgAsEIBXGJKABRzAGcANInacAwrkgA7JFJi8IA4Q2asOXAMowUMYGn5wAvnDjZcBIuhgBaHOqhlSmNlIzAIUuAA0AFGABcIuoS4B6y8nz8ADy0AXD8MFDAUgDmRgB8AJTUpCYmRDBsUJ5SbAA2ZQCEpIakpEgAHpTwACZIaGUoRKYubh5wAO6MLKJcUdxwjZxSLQZq4pJhcgoCUShSAJ7pwmKTDdOziMQwAHQh0uEAKhtgSOPp6T65eWiLMnKBuwBkJshWZ28rjc7tx0qRMoE-hgAaF3jAxJ1+NEAPIgRjjYQAayQGwgmCCC1h4RW0XWW3ScB+KhG9hJUTED0p9GG8002l0+np6QA3HVSGUkPAGgAmOAAXkGLNGUB8XkycAA9Aq4BNgAZYoEEklUkYgA)

Note that in newer versions on TS, we can use conditional types to extract `P` from `C` without the need for the intersection trick (although there might be pre 2.8 compatibly constraints here, or performance constraints that I might not be aware of). So we could rewrite  that HOC as:

```
export declare function withRouter<C extends React.ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any>>>(
    component: C 
): React.ComponentClass<Omit<React.ComponentProps<C>, keyof RouteComponentProps<any>> & WithRouterProps<C>> & WithRouterStatics<C>;


let x2 = withRouter(X) // P is { p: string }
```

`React.ComponentProps` is a conditional type defined in react.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChRJY4BvOAdWBgAsEIBXGJKABRzAGcANInacAwrkgA7JFJi8IA4Q2asOXAMowUMYGn5wAvnDjZcBIuhgBaHOqhlSmNlIzAIUuAA0AFGABcIuoS4B6y8nz8ADy0AXD8MFDAUgDmRgB8AJTUpCYmRDBsUJ5SbAA2ZQCEpIakpEgAHpTwACZIaGUoRKYubh5wAO6MLKJcUWJwjZxSLQbIVgB0IdLhACoAnmBIUWrikmFyCgJRKFLr6Rc+uXlo+zJygROkmYHzGEt34WKd-NEA8iBGDtiDAPqF7hFFNExOlhABrJDrCCYIJ7cHhI7RU7ndJwABk9GGuy4mPGF3xhNUoygWh0emh6QA3HVSGUkPAGgAmOAAXkGROpPi8mTgAHpRXBuHBgAZYoEEklUkYgA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer, now I understand. It's always a pleasure to read your answers, keep up the good work.